# Tricky C Program to find even and odd

Tags: c

This is a challenging problem I came across while I was giving my internship exam in Microsoft. The question goes like this:

> User inputs a decimal number.  The output should show whether the number is even or odd subject to constraint that only one `printf`, and no binary operator, logical operator, arithmetic operator, `if-else` and `switch-case` can be used.

So any ideas?

Comment: may be related to unary operators ,i guess

Comment: These kind of interview questions annoy me. They have close to nothing to do with most day-to-day programming.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I sympathize with @yshavit's response.  These questions are fairly silly; they mainly depend on 'have you seen it before' and 'can you work out what is left for you to use'?  The constraints given are irrelevant to real-world programming.

Comment: I agree that interview questions like this are generally impractical. An on a personal note, they usually send me the "we're so elite we can waste your time on brain teasers" signal. However SO doesn't make provisions for "silliness", so let's all get off of our respective soap boxes and try to see if this question can be answered. It's a good question.

Comment: They may be irrelevant but if you have a group of people then the fastest few people to work it out are generally going to be those that can think on their feet and improvise with what they have to get a solution. Those who can't will just Google .. People like Microsoft obviously look for those that can think things through when they seem impossible.

Comment: This question is not relevant to any real-world programming problem.  The constraints on the problem make it irrelevant to anyone but interviewees, and only relevant then after the fact.  Voted to close as too localized.

Comment: Hey OP, do you know if this actually has an answer? It could be that this is given to watch candidates squirm. Sometimes they just want to see how you hold up under pressure.

Comment: Does it have to work on a machine using one's complement, rather than two's complement? Can we assume a certain processor? If so, the solution is obviously to write inline assembly code, which doesn't use any C operators.

Comment: What's left?  The question doesn't rule out loops; there are the increment and decrement operators; there are subscripts, addresses, dereferencing, function calls, but they don't seem likely to help; it isn't clear whether bitwise not (`~`) is precluded, whereas `!` probably is as it is a logical operator, albeit a unary one.  The ternary operator can be used, it seems; the comma operator cannot.  What am I missing?  (The binary operator ban removes assignments, shifts, arithmetic, etc.)

Comment: yes it has a answer, for sure, because one of my batchmate answered,he got the intership too;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/909016/366904

Comment: It was stupid that this was closed. This will work I think: `printf("Number is odd: %d", (int)fmod((float)i, (float)2));`

Comment: ya i guess it will work, because fmod is a function

Comment: I was thinking something clever involving pointers, since subscript notation is actually addition under the hood. So no arithmetic operators are used, but arithmetic is still accomplished.

Comment: @Chris `[]` would be a binary operator wouldn't it

Comment: @SethCarnegie I don't usually consider that to be binary, no. However I honestly don't know the answer to that. I'm hoping not in this case.

Comment: @SethCarnegie,@Chris check this link, it is list of all binary operators , [] is not in the list.    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @sum2000 I don't see a list of binary operators, that page does not contain the word "binary". What section is it in

Comment: sorry i posted wrong link , this is http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_062.HTM

Comment: @sum2000 where did it get the information from? If the standard, then ok, but if not, then the validity is dubious. Plus it looks like some documentation for some HP product.

Comment: @sum2000 ah, it says "This document is the language reference manual for DEC C." What is DEC C?

Comment: oh, did'nt look that deeply, i guess then i have to read C documentation

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963106/find-even-odd-number-without-using-mathematical-bitwise-operator

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy that question had less restrictions and the aswers won't work as-is, but I think you could make some work

Comment: ya the selected answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963106/find-even-odd-number-without-using-mathematical-bitwise-operator  might work

Comment: @sum2000 you'd need to rewrite it not to use `=`, `.`, and `==`, then it would work I think. Actually, I don't know if you can do it in just C (that question was C++ which has constructors, casts, initialiser lists, etc)

Comment: yes, that's why i didn't post that answer, but using struct is a nice approach

Comment: it has as solution even without cheating, @ThomasPadron-McCarthy just didn't go far enough to avoid the `[]` operator. But this array based solution would be much easier to write up with designated initializers, which is C99. so my guess would be that Microsoft wouldn't allow that either? Just crazy. Confirms me much in my opinion to avoid buying products from vendors that have recruting criteria like this.

Comment: The point is not to solve this particular problem.  The point is to demonstrate that you can solve problems in general.  The artificial constraints are a way of making the problem challenging.  A problem of similar difficulty without artificial constraints would probably take substantially longer to describe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seth Carnegie's answer can fail for certain inputs. In particular, on my system, it fails for an input of `2147483647`, indicating that it's even (at least on my system), because converting that value to `float` loses precision.

Here's an improved solution based on his:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *const even_or_odd[] = { "even", "odd" };
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i ++) {
        const int n = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d is %s\n",
               n,
               even_or_odd[(int)fmod((unsigned char)n, 2.0)]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `for (int i = ...` syntax is "new" in C99; if your compiler doesn't support it, declare `int i`; above the loop.

The values to be tested are taken from the command line arguments.  It would be easy enough to modify the program so they're taken from `stdin` or elsewhere.

The `atoi()` function does no error checking, so don't expect meaningful results if you give it something that's not a decimal integer.

Converting the value of `n` to `unsigned char` before passing it to `fmod()` give a result with the same parity (odd-or-evenness) as `n`, but that won't lose precision when converted to `double` (that conversion happens implicitly because `fmod()` takes `double` arguments).  The standard-defined semantics of conversion to an unsigned type are such that this will work correctly even on systems that use a representation other than two's-complement.

It's just barely possible that converting from `unsigned char` to `double` could lose precision.  This would require `unsigned char` to have an implausibly large upper bound.  `double` must have at least 10 decimal digits of precision, or about 33 or 34 bits; losing precision would require `unsigned char` to be *at least* 34 or so bits (it's likely I have an off-by-one error or two in there).  Such a system could be conforming, but I doubt that any such systems exist in the real world.

Comment: I didn't downvote. All I did was upvote.

Answer (score 47):

Silly questions call for silly answers.

```
printf("Yes, the number is even or odd\n");
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. All I did was http://i.stack.imgur.com/WG71u.gif

Comment: +1, though maybe the word  "whether" precludes this answer

Comment: If I could upvote this again, I would.

Comment: Given the wording ("..shows whether the number.."), my first instinct was to "solve" it by `printf("%d\n", x)`, which obviously shows whether the number is even or odd.

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed that this is my top scoring answer on StackOverflow.  (No, I'm not asking people to correct that situation.)

Comment: @KeithThompson my answer to this question is also tied with two others to be my top answer on SO :(

Answer (score 27):

This will work:

```
printf("Number is odd? %d\n", (int)fmod((float)i, (float)2));
```

Or better if you can use the conditional operator:

```
printf("Number is %s\n", (int)fmod((float)i, (float)2) ? "odd" : "even");
```

Comment: i could'nt find better solution than this till now

Comment: @sum2000 tell me when you find a better one

Comment: It's called the conditional operator. "ternary operator" is just a category, much like "binary operator" is for `=`, `|` and `&`.

Comment: @BoltClock it is the only ternary operator in C++ right?

Comment: @BoltClock then it is "the" ternary operator :) I'll change it anyway though since that is a more precise name and the other will be invalid if another ternary operator is added to C++ in the future (unlikely though it may be)

Comment: Alternatively one could use `div()/ldiv()/lldiv()` from `stdlib.h`. Or bitfields (not portable).

Comment: In the interview question, arithmetic operators, such as Modulo(%) were excluded.   So `fmod` kinda looks like "cheating" to me.  In this use, it is functionally identical to %, yes?

Comment: @abelenky Yes it is. They didn't say you couldn't use the `()` operator though; it uses the `()` operator with the address of the first instruction of `fmod`, `i`, and `2` as operands :)

Comment: This is unreliable.  Typically `float` is 32 bits, which isn't big enough to hold a large `int` value without loss of precision.  Experiment shows that, for values `INT_MAX-1` and `INT_MAX`, the above works correctly using gcc with default options, but fails (reports both as even) using `gcc -ffloat-store`, which prevents intermediate floating-point calculations from being stored in greater precision.  Changing all occurrences of `float` to `double` helps (`fmod()` operates on `double`s anyway), but it's still possible that `double` can't hold all `int` values without loss of precision.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Can't you just cast to `signed char` first?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Strictly speaking, there's no guarantee that `float`, or even `double` or `long double`, can hold all the values representable in a `signed char` without loss of precision (consider an exotic system with `CHAR_BIT==64`).  Converting an `int` value to `signed char` yields an implementation-defined result if the value is outside the range of `signed char`; it typically retains the signedness of the operand, but that's not guaranteed (I'm not sure what would happen on a ones'-complement system).  Using `unsigned char` avoids that, but it doesn't solve the range problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Oh huh, I see...

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while (*argv[1]) { ++argv[1]; } --argv[1];
    printf("Your number is even %.1s odd\n", &("<><><><><>"[atoi(argv[1])]));
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 6):

Let x be the variable to determine. The following code will print 0 if x is even, 1 - if odd:

```
union
{
    unsigned char tmp:1;
} u;

u.tmp = x;    
printf("%d", u.tmp);
```

Comment: This uses two binary operators three times.

Comment: @SethCarnegie which two? i could make out one.

Comment: @sum2000 = and .

Answer (score 3):

I consider the accepted answer using fmod to be breaking the "no arithmetic operators" rule. Here's a solution using only structs and casts to find out what the least significant bit is (signifying odd or even):

```
float f = ...;

struct intStruct {
    int i;
};
struct intStruct is;
is.i = (int)f;

struct bitField {
    unsigned int odd : 1;
    unsigned int padding: 15; // to round out to 16 bits
};
struct bitField *bf_ptr;
bf_ptr = (struct bitField *)&is;
struct bitField bf = *bf_ptr;

printf("Odd? %d", bf.odd);
```

Comment: What is the effect of declaring a `*bf_ptr` and then a separate `bf`? And why are you allowed to assign a bitField pointer to a variable bitField type? Lastly, how does C know how to cast the `is` into a `bitField *`? That is to say, how does it conveniently convert `i` into `odd` and `padding`? Your answer here seems very clever but contains much C that is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

No ternary operator:

```
int n;
char *answers[] = { "even", "odd" };
scanf("%i", &n);
printf("%s\n", answers[(int) fmod(n, 2.0)]);
```

Comment: subtraction is a binary and arithmetic operator, and `[]` can be counted as a binary op

Comment: Good point! I'll delete the second half.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, and a ternary operator can be considered a logical operator :)

Comment: true true, though all operators behave logically, so they can all be seen as logical operators :) The answer still works without it though

Comment: @SethCarnegie . is unary or binary , i have confusion.?

Comment: @sum2000 . Is binary because it requires two operands

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that avoids using fmod at all. It works using the character representation of the number, checking whether the last digit is in {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}.

The big trouble is finding the last digit.

The restrictions of the problem are onerous.

1. no binary operators:  no assignments (`=`) or array indexing (`[]`) or even structure reference (`.`)
2. no logical operators: no negation (`!`) or shortcut tricks (`&&`) or equality (`==`)
3. no arithmetic operators: no increment (`++`)
4. no `if` or `switch`
5. only one `printf`

About the only operators left are `*`, `&`, `~`, `?:` and `sizeof`.

Most of the code is trying to find the last digit in the string. The only binary operator used is in the `main()` driver, to get `argv[1]`. (The square brackets for `c[2]` are declaration syntax, not an operator)

I worked around assignment by using a function call, and `memcpy`.
I worked around `if` by using `while` and munging the test.
I worker around `!=` by assuming `NULL == 0`.

On the plus side, this function works with really big numbers!

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* null_pointer;
char c[2];

// If s is not null, copy *s to *save, and change *s to '~'
// Return s
char* copy_zap_char_not_null(char* save, char* s) {
    char* p;
    memcpy(&p, &s, sizeof(char*));
    while (p) {
        memcpy(save, p, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(p, "~", sizeof(char));
        memcpy(&p, &null_pointer, sizeof(void*));
    }
    return s;
}

int print_even_odd(char* s)
{
    while (copy_zap_char_not_null(c, strpbrk(s, "0123456789"))) {}
    printf("%s\n", ( strpbrk(c, "02468") ? "even" : "odd" ) );
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    print_even_odd(argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i, count;
    char c, *p, strnum[32];

    printf("enter input number:");
    scanf("%d%*c", &i);
    sprintf(strnum, "%d", i);//or itoa, deprecated.
    p=&strnum[strlen(strnum)];
    count=sscanf(&p[-1], "%[02468]c", &c);
    printf("%d is %s\n", i, count ? "even" : "odd");
    return 0;
}


//p=strrev(strnum);//strrev is deprecated. But It works Microsoft C Compiler.
//count=sscanf(p, "%[02468]c", &c);


//printf("%d is %s\n", i, sscanf(strrev(itoa(i,(char*)malloc(32),10)), "%[02468]c", (char*)(malloc(1)) ? "even" : "odd");
```

Comment: ++, -- is arithmetic operator? thanks. update code.

Comment: So, do not use it. '-1' '-' Is not an arithmetic operator.

Comment: I can use the strrev if necessary. It is VC10 (cl) works.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Yes, the `-` in `-1` is an arithmetic operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{  int  number;
   scanf("%d",&number);
    number&1 && printf("Odd") || printf("even");

}
```

or

```
int main()
{
int number ;
char arr[][2]={"Even","Odd"};
printf("%s\n",arr[number%2]);
}
```

Comment: No binary operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
n&1? puts("NO"):puts("YES");
```

Comment: close, but this one doesn't use a printf as required, does it?

Comment: No binary operators.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do this by using bitwise AND operator...

```
scanf("%d",&n);
if( n & 1 == 1) // if last bit in numbers is 1, 'n' is odd , 0 for even
```

Later you can use if else and switch to display whether the number if even or odd.

Comment: `==` is a logical operator and `&` is a binary one. Double failure.

Comment: Also, the precedence is wrong. `==` has higher precedence than `&`. (But in this case, the code will work anyway because `1 == 1` is `1` and `n & 1` is what you wanted after all.)

Answer (score -2):

The best I could come up with...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int number;
    char oddness[4+1];
    printf("Type an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("I need some help here, user. Is it even or odd? ");
    scanf("%s", oddness);
    printf("%d is %s.\n", number, oddness);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It says "the user inputs a number. The output should be..." it doesn't say the user can freely input things. Also the user can lie or be mistaken in which the program is wrong.

Comment: sorry, only one `printf` can be used.

Answer (score -3):

If the user is referring decimal numbers as floating point numbers and not base 10 numbers then this could be a possible answer.

```
printf("Floating point numbers are neither even nor odd.");
```

[An even number is an integer that is "evenly divisible" by 2, i.e., divisible by 2 without remainder; an odd number is an integer that is not evenly divisible by 2.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: Who says decimal numbers can't be integers?

Comment: Also "decimal" could be argued to mean "in base 10"

Comment: Its is unclear from the question that whether he is referring decimal numbers as base 10 numbers or floating point number. @sum2000: kindly update the question to make it more clear.